# Passing a newly initialized UIImageView to a property (type UIImageView) of a class give nil?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `CustomCollectionViewController` and a `CustomCollectionViewCell`. I dragged and dropped a `UIImageView` onto the `CustomCollectionViewCell` in storyboard and bound that in code.

Then I tried to initialized the cell within `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` with this line:

`customCell.imageView = UIImageView(image: images[indexPath.item])`

it didn't work, `customCell.imageView` was `nil` when `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` returns. But with `imageCell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.item]`, it worked.

Why is that so? Thanks.

---

Code snippet:

Inside `class CustomCollectionViewController`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath)

    if let imageCell = cell as? ImageCollectionViewCell, images[indexPath.item] != nil {
        imageCell.imageView = UIImageView(image: images[indexPath.item])  // doesn't work, cell.imageView would be nil
        imageCell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.item]  // work
    }

    return cell
}
```

And:

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Long answer:**

Let's name your old ImageView (the one from storyboard) as A and new one (created at code) as B `UIImageView(image: images[indexPath.item])`
The variable will be called just reference

You have set your reference to be weak, which means, as soon as it loses any strong reference (like being in a view hierarchy) it is destroyed. When you assigned it to be B, that B wasn't assigned to anywhere else so it was immediately destroyed so your reference became nil. Your A is still on cell (in subviews array and arrays are tend to hold strong references) as long as you remove it from hierarchy. You have to understand difference between link reference (weak or strong) and being a subview in a view (strong). Before you made any changes in code, the A imageView had two links - weak pointer in your code and strong pointer in cell hierarchy. When you replaced reference with B, A lost weak, but still has strong reference in cell itself. B only had weak so it was immediately destroyed before any actual use of it

You have problems with your logic too. Just because you change reference to your B imageView, doesn't mean the image will appear in your cell. Your B needs to be set it's frame or constraints and added in some view hierarchy (cell). What you actually need is just change your A.image property to your new image and that's it `imageCell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.item]`

Please read more about memory management and weak, strong references

**Short answer:**

Remove this line

`imageCell.imageView = UIImageView(image: images[indexPath.item])`

So your code looks like

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath)

    if let imageCell = cell as? ImageCollectionViewCell,
       let image = images[indexPath.item]
    {
        imageCell.imageView.image = image
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: The key: _You have to understand difference between link reference (weak or strong) and being a subview in a view (strong)._

Comment: Thank you very much for the in-depth answer!

Answer (score 0):

Since the imageView is declared `weak`

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

assigning a new instance to it makes it `nil` as lhs can't retain rhs , look to warning

[image]

If you want it to work then remove the `weak` as the default is `strong`

```
@IBOutle var imageView: UIImageView!
```

but it'll make no sense to your current case so just only assign the image

Comment: The problem is not just references but also view hierarchy holding strong reference

Comment: what  view hierarchy you mean ?? if cell xib /protypecell/programmatically cell it won't prevent deallocation of imageView

Comment: The old imageView (which was set through storyboard) is hold strong as it is still in cell's children array (arrays are holding strong references), so even if you change this variable to strong, the old imageView is still there - it didn't disappear automagically - you just lost direct reference to it...

Comment: I didn't say it will disappear , removing the weak will let the imageView var to be non-nil

Comment: Or just create as local var, add it to cell as subview and then change variable. That way weak reference will be non-nil

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to set the imageView property. This is an outlet, instantiated by the storyboard/xib. I'm guessing that the new UIImageView you create is not retained, since imageView is declared as weak.

You should avoid "recreating" any views or controls like this, if they are added using Interface builder in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers already mentioned the problem is that `imageCell.imageView` is weak, so it only references an ImageView that is retained strongly in another place.

imageCell.imageView is originally referencing the ImageView you dragged and dropped in the storyboard. When a View is contained in another View it is strongly retained.

If you want to replace that ImageView you need to create a strong reference to your new ImageView, for example adding it to another View, something like this:

```
let newImageView = UIImageView(image: images[indexPath.item])
imageCell.contentView.addSubview(newImageView)
imageCell.imageView = newImageView
```

But as others have mentioned before, probably is best that you just replace the UIImage of your current ImageView.

Comment: fix imageCell.contentView.addSubview(newImageView)